# Install gcc4.9 on openSuse 13.1

Tags: software-installation, opensuse, gcc, g++

I need to download and install g++4.9 in order to work with regex in c++11 for a school project. I downloaded the source but it seems it does not work .. I searched for the rpm and 1-ClickInstall and everything I find seems not to work. So I'm here looking for a solution. How can I install g++4.9 on OpenSuse 13.1 ?

Thanks !

Comment: g++4.8 doesn't support regex.

Comment: What went wrong when you tried to use the `gcc` 4.9 source?

Comment: Also, what RPMs did you try?

Comment: @StephenKitt I did the mkdir objdir , cd objdir, ../gcc4.9.2/configure, make, sudo make install, but g++4.9 is not found, I'm trying to recompile it again after having my pc reinstalled. About the RPM I did not find any for openSuse, I tried one for an other linux but it asks for dependency ..

Comment: When building from source you may just end up with `g++`, not `g++4.9` (and it would be `g++-4.9` anyway). If your rebuild doesn't work, you could always try the OpenSuse 13.2 RPMs from http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/opensuse/13.2/x86_64/gcc49-4.9.0+r211729-2.1.7.x86_64.html (and their dependencies as necessary)...

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot the '-'. I'm trying to install the RPM. THanks for your help

Comment: The dependecies are not "downloadable" ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

openSUSE has some "extended" repositories, that include various tools (gcc-4.9 and gcc-5.0 beta are there).

From root shell add repository and enable it:

```
# zypper ar http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/openSUSE_13.1/ devel-gcc
```

Refresh repository cached metadata:

```
# zypper ref
```

Install g++ 4.9

```
# zypper in gcc49-c++
```

To use it, explicitly compile with `g++-4.9`

---

Check other packages at http://software.opensuse.org/